# Perl running a batch file @echo command not found

Tags: perl, command-line, batch-file

I am using [mr](http://joeyh.name/code/mr/) on Windows and it allows running arbitrary commands before/after any repository action. As far as I can see this is done simply by invoking perl's `system` function. However something seems very wrong with my setup: when making mr run the following batch file, located in d:

```
@echo off
copy /Y foo.bat bar.bat
```

I get errors on the most basic windows commands:

```
d:/foo.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
d:/foo.bat: line 2: copy: command not found
```

To make sure mr isn't the problem, I ran `perl -e 'system( "d:/foo.bat" )'` but the output is the same.

Using xcopy instead of copy, it seems the xcopy command is found since the output is now

```
d:/foo.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
Invalid number of parameters
```

However I have no idea what could be wrong with the parameters. I figured maybe the problem is the batch file hasn't full access to the standard command environment so I tried running it explicitly via `perl -e 'system( "cmd /c d:\foo.bat" )'` but that just starts cmd and does not run the command (I have to exit the command line to get back to the one where I was).

What is wrong here? A detailed explanation would be great. Also, how do I solve this? I prefer a solution that leaves the batch file as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The echo directive is executed directly by the running command-prompt instance.
But perl is *[launching a new process](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)* with your command. You need to run your script within a cmd instance, for those commands to work.

Your `cmd /c` must work. Check if you have spaces in the path you are supplying to it.
You can use a parametrized way of passing arguments,

```
@array = qw("/c", "path/to/xyz.bat");
system("cmd.exe", @array);
```

The echo directive is **not** an executable and hence, it errors out.
The same is true of the `copy` command also. It is **not** an executable, while `xcopy.exe` is.

Comment: ok I see that cmd will be necessary to properly interpret the batch file. However I cannot use the parametrized way (the system call is in the mr script and I do not want to modify it), the command should be a one liner. I think the cmd call is not working due to quoting / escaping rules but I'm going to look into it.

Comment: got it, the clue was in your answer already: I was using `cmd` but that invokes `cmd.bat` which is not an executable so cause problems, using `cmd.eze` makes everything work. Thanks~