# Error when running add-user.bat for Wildfly server

Tags: java, batch-file, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to access the Administration console for Wildfly, but first it says I must

> run the  'add-user.bat' file in [server installation directory]/bin/

Which I do but then get an error saying, well, look:

[image]

When I simply try and run the file by double clicking it I get:

[image]

I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit (Urgh) and Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622207/perl-running-a-batch-file-echo-command-not-found) might help. try using cmd /c add-user.bat or just run add-user.bat without any command before it and Check Java home [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172611/add-user-bat-on-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified).

Comment: Is this the bat [file](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/build/src/main/resources/bin/add-user.bat).

Comment: Ok I think there is problem with Environment variable (java or JBOSS) try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172611/add-user-bat-on-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)

Comment: Vivek you were right! All I needed to do is correct my JAVA_HOME variable, it was pointing to jdk/bin/ where it should just point to the root of the jdk installation